# How to find the equation of the plane that tangent to this surface?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the the equation of the plane that tangent to $x^2+2y^2+4z^2+xy+3yz=1$ and is paralel to $y=0$ plane

first I found the gradient vector $\nabla f\left( x,y,z\right)=(2x+y)i+(4y+x+3z)j+(8z+3y)k
 $

and I   equalized this to normal vector which is $(0,1,0)$

$2x_0+y_0=0$

$4y_0+x_0+3z_0=1$

$8z_0+3y=0$

and I found $y=\frac{8}{19}$

so the plane's equation should be $0(x-x_0)+(y-\frac{8}{19})+0(z-z_0)=0$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the tangent plane will have an equation of the form $y=y_0$, but you should have set the gradient equal to $(0,\lambda,0)$, since we do not know *a priori* that the gradient has unit magnitude.  Then we can solve for $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in terms of $\lambda$.  When we plug $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ back into our equation for the surface, we can solve for $\lambda$.  We are not be surprised to obtain 2 solutions for $\lambda$. That just means there are 2 tangent planes of the desired form.  We can use the values of $\lambda$ to obtain the tangent points $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and the equations of the tangent planes.